# Не могу поменять автора материала, возникает ошибка ajax, скрины и код внутри (drupal)

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

При попытке поменять автора материала всплывает диалоговое окно 403 ошибка якобы у меня, как суперадмин запреoен доступ, не пойму в чем дело.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А права на папку выставлены корректно?

Comment: @VenZell Эх да знать бы еще на какую)) но как минимум на чтение везде стоят

Comment: Разверните локальную копию сайта, выставьте глобально права 777 в папке с проектом и проверьте наличие ошибки. Если ушла - по-любому в них права. Сверяйтесь с требованиями Drupal.